# How to solve stored Xss checkmarx issue on byte array/file writing in java

Tags: java, file, checkmarx

I am getting stored xss issue in file read

The issue is when writing the content, please suggest solution.
Thanks in advance

My code is as below

```
fileIn = new FileInputStreaam(file) ;
  While((br=fileIn.read(buffer))! =-1) 
  {
     Outputstream. Write(buffer,0,br);
  }
```

Comment: *My code is as below* No it isn't. That wouldn't compile

Comment: Please share with us more information, such as the full error message from *Checkmarx* and all the related code.